# Is There a way to debug RabbitMQ Consumer (php-ampqlib) using PhpStorm and Xdebug?

Tags: php, cakephp, rabbitmq, phpstorm, xdebug

Here is my dev setup:

**IDE:** PhpStorm 9.0.2
**Debugger:** Xdebug 2.3.3
**Message Queue Server:** RabbitMQ 3.5.6
**PHP Lib to connect to RabbitMQ Server:** php-ampqlib

To start my consumer I'm using a CakePHP Task and run like this:

> ../lib/Cake/Console/cake cron message_trigger_consumer

When I run this command, my consumer is UP and waiting for a message, that will comes from a **Producer** (for example: Save Form Button that send a confirmation email). Until here, everything is OK, but my two questions are: 
1) Is There a way to debug the **Consumer**? In my point of view, **Consumer** is in a different process, that's why Xdebug cannot debug it
2) Have some way to attach my **Consumer** process to my current debug in PhpStorm + Xdebug?

If you not understand my question, please, show me your doubts.

Comment: Debug it as any other PHP script.

Comment: Could you explain how?

Comment: Could you share your PHP xdebug.ini settings ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Web Context Xdebugs Sessions are usually triggered by an Cookie named `XDEBUG_SESSION`.

On The CLI there are no cookies, so you will have to tell xdebug to start a session by hand:

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=your-server-name-configured-in-php-storm"
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=ip_of_php_storm_pc idekey=PHPSTORM"
```

Then in PHP Storm just listen to incoming connections via the phone handset icon.

Its working great!

Comment: Your solution works when I using php script without CakePHP framework. I tried a plugin called FIREHOSE from RabbitMQ and works more or less. I think CLI using CakePHP is my problem.

Comment: Please share your xdebug.* settings values from `php -i`

Comment: zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port= 9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM

Answer (score 0):

#### Xdebug and RabbitMQ consumer commands

Running `cake cron message_trigger_consumer` doesn't trigger xdebug in the IDE. To make PhpStorm aware of the connection you need to prefix the command with the environment variable:

`PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=example.com" cake cron message_trigger_consumer`

Replace `example.com` with appropriate server name.